# Issue executing multiple Batch files within main batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have 3 batch files which consume a common variable-'target'. These batch files need to be executed one after the other. I am using one main batch file where I am trying to call these three batch files. But the execution stops right after first batch job is done. If I execute these batch jobs individually within that main batch file, they gets executed fine without any issue. Not sure what's missing here.

Main batch file (MainBatch.bat) contents:

```
set target=OHD121
CALL C:\Users\abc\x1.bat
pause
CALL C:\Users\abc\y1.bat
pause
CALL C:\Users\abc\z1.bat
pause
```

Comment: Does `x1.bat` have `EXIT` at the end? Have you tried `EXIT /B`? See `EXIT /?` for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the reason behind the issue. in my called bat files, I have another bat file for which I wasn't using call and that's why the control wasn't returning to original call action to perform subsequent steps.